# How can I use both Azure Bizspark and Pay-as-you-go subscriptions for same Resource Manager VM (not classic)

Tags: ubuntu, azure, virtual-machine, bizspark

This case is a bit confusing but I'll try to summarize it.

I have a new VM (Ubuntu 14) on Azure Bizspark subscription and, I want to create a storage and a `.vhd` on it with my Pay-as-you-go subscription and attach to Ubuntu.

At this point, I setup Azure-CLI and select my Pay-as-you-go subscription and run the creating `.vhd` code. But nothing happened, because Bizspark server didn't appear. I guess we can't use both subscriptions together.

```
$azure vm disk list
$azure vm disk attach-new myServer 50
```

Is there a way to attach a .vhd from direct url like `blob.core.windows.net/vhd-store/data1.vhd` instead of creating new one by using *Azure-CL*, *Powershell* or `ssh` connection  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Virtual Machine and its disks have to be in the same Azure subscription.